# Looping Through Excel Files using Openpyxl getting Worksheet object is not callable error

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am currently trying to loop through different excel files in a folder and amalgamate them into one main file. However, when trying to implement this loop I am getting the error Worksheet object is not callable.

Here is the code (apologies for my poor naming conventions):

```
 import openpyxl

 import openpyxl.formula

 import pandas

 import os

 from openpyxl import Workbook
 from openpyxl.styles import Alignment
 from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter
 from openpyxl import load_workbook
 from openpyxl import worksheet
 #
 # Declaration of openpyxl variables
 #
 directoryPath = "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\ExcelForReverse\\"
 productionPath = "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\TransformedReverse.xlsx"
 book_empty = Workbook()
 book_empty.save(productionPath)
 book_empty.create_sheet("Internals")
 book_empty.create_sheet("Externals")
 book_empty.create_sheet("All Formatted")
 del_sheet = book_empty["Sheet"]
 book_empty.remove_sheet(del_sheet)
 book_empty.save(productionPath)
 sheet_externals_con = book_empty["Externals"]
 sheet_internals_con = book_empty["Internals"]
 os.chdir(directoryPath)
 folder_list = os.listdir(directoryPath)
 attempt = 1
 rowvar_externals = 2
 rowvar_internals = 2
 for folders, sub_folders, file in os.walk(directoryPath):  
   for name in file:
     if name.endswith(".xlsx"):
        filename = os.path.join(name)
        print(filename)
        wb_controller = load_workbook(filename, data_only=True)
        sheet_controller_internals = wb_controller['Input INT']
        sheet_controller_externals = wb_controller['Input EXT']
        numOfRows_externals = sheet_controller_externals.max_row
        numOfCols_externals = sheet_controller_externals.max_column
        numOfRows_internals = sheet_controller_internals.max_row
        numOfCols_internals = sheet_controller_internals.max_column
        if attempt == 1:
            for i in range(1,numOfCols_externals+1):
                sheet_externals_con.cell(row = 1, column = i).value = sheet_controller_externals.cell(row = 3, column = i).value

        for r in range(4,numOfRows_externals+1):
            for i in range(1,numOfCols_externals+1):
                sheet_externals_con.cell(row = rowvar_externals, column = i).value = sheet_controller_externals(row = r, column = i).value
            rowvar_externals = rowvar_externals + 1 

        if attempt == 1:
            for i in range(1,numOfCols_internals+1):
                sheet_internals_con.cell(row = 1, column = i).value = sheet_controller_internals.cell(row = 3, column = i).value            

        for r in range(4,numOfRows_internals+1):
            for i in range(1,numOfCols_internals+1):
                sheet_internals_con.cell(row = rowvar_internals, column = i).value = sheet_controller_internals(row = r, column = i).value 
            rowvar_internals = rowvar_internals + 1

        attempt = attempt + 1
        print("Worked")
book_empty.save(productionPath)
```

The Error Message:
File line 48, in 
  sheet_externals_con.cell(row = rowvar_externals, column = i).value = sheet_controller_externals(row = r, column = i).value

builtins.TypeError: 'Worksheet' object is not callable

Comment: `File line 48` i'm not counting through 48 lines man

Comment: @SuperStew the actual line of code is shown in the error message so there would be no need to count lines but I definitely should make a comment in the code itself to make it more apparent next time.

Comment: Please try and keep your code down to the minium required. Quoting the line with the problem is good, but also gives you the solution. We have to backtrack a whole screen to try and work things out. Hint: code like this is likely to be a bitch to maintain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should the line not read:

```
sheet_externals_con.cell(row = rowvar_externals, column = i).value = sheet_controller_externals.cell(row = r, column = i).value
```

Where

`sheet_controller_externals` -> `sheet_controller_externals.cell`

Comment: Yikes, can't believe I missed that. That is what fixed the error. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help. Be sure to mark the question as resolved!